# Combinations with repetitions and inconsistent results?

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry for the terrible title. I wasn't quite sure how to word it.

Say we have 10 total distinct items, numbered from 1 to 10. Also, we assign them colors so that:

$red = \{1, 2, 3\}$
$blue = \{4, 5, 6\}$
$green = \{7, 8, 9, 10\}$

Now, we choose 3 items (unordered) from the 10 total items, with replacement. I am trying to find the probability that the 3 items are all different colors. I approached this question from 2 ways:

$\frac{3 * 3 * 4}{220} = 0.1636$, since we have $3 * 3 * 4$ ways of choosing 1 from each color, and 220 ways of choosing 3 from 10 with repetition total.

$\frac{3}{10}\frac{3}{10}\frac{4}{10} * 3! = 0.216$, which is the chance of choosing a red item, then a blue item, then a green item. But any order of choosing different colors would work, so I multiply by the number of permutations of 3 items.

I had expected to get the same result in both calculations, and am confused as to why I didn't. Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: If you are selecting with repetition, there are $10$ choices for each item, or $10^3 = 1000$ ways to choose three items.

Comment: Wouldn't that be permutations with repetition, though? In this case I don't care about order.

Comment: Your first method is wrong because ${10 \choose 3}$ would mean you are selecting $3$ items without replacement (and without consideration for order).

Comment: You can choose three items from ten *without replacement* in $\binom{10}{3}$ ways.  However, you wish to choose items *with replacement*, so there are ten choices for each item.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: But in that calculation the order matters. If it is a combination with repetition, it's a "stars and bars" problem, and the answer is $\binom{10+3-1}{3}=\binom{12}{3}$, which gives the correct answer of $220$.

Comment: That is what I was thinking as well, so I was fairly confident the first solution is correct, but I am not sure because the second solution gave a different probability...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  Those $220$ outcomes are not equally likely to occur.  There are $3!$ ways to obtain three different numbers (such as $1, 2, 3$) with three selections but only one way to obtain the same number (such as $1, 1, 1$) on each selection.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: That's a good point, but your comments above obscure that; it's not a question of how many possible *outcomes* there are, which is what you seem to address in your comments.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig for pointing out that the outcomes are not equally likely, however! That's a very good point. In that case, what would be the full formula you'd use?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see what you are saying.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @EachOneChew I would have used your second method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second argument is correct.

Your ${12 \choose 3}=220$ has no justification: it is the number of ways of distributing $3$ colours among $10$ items in an indistinct non-equally probable way.

Here is a simulation in R

```
set.seed(2021)
allcolours <- function(replacement){
  items <- c(rep("red",3), rep("blue",3), rep("green",4))
  sam <- sample(items, 3, replace=replacement)
  "red" %in% sam & "blue" %in% sam & "green" %in% sam 
  }
mean(replicate(10^6, allcolours(TRUE)))
# 0.215761
```

which is close enough to $0.216$ to be persuasive.

If you were drawing without replacement, the answer would be $3!\frac{3 \times 3 \times 4}{10 \times 9 \times 8} = \frac3{10}$.  The same simulation but changing the `TRUE`  to `FALSE` would give $0.299539$, again persuasive

Comment: Ahhhh, I've noticed that treating the items as ordered gives me the correct result in both cases. Does this apply in general to when I am calculating probability?

Comment: @EachOneChew I would say that in a counting question like this, it is often a good approach to find first the total number of equally likely possibilities for the denominator (here $10 \times 10 \times 10$ with replacement and $10\times 9 \times 8$ without replacement).  Combinations sometimes give a shortcut to the correct answer, but at the risk of sometimes being misleading